# Node.js error: Each then() should return a value or throw?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions, eslint

My Cloud Functions node.js file is presenting this error:

```
477:4   error    Each then() should return a value or throw
```

However I am returning a value in the `then()`, (i'm returning `1`)

Line 477 is the line with `if (snapshot.exists){`

**staging.js**

```
function manuallyDeleteObj(objDoc, fcmToken){
    return objDoc.get().then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists){
                return objDoc.delete().then(() => {
                    return 1;
                }).catch(() => {
                    return 0;
                })
            }
            else {
                const dataMsg = { data: { type: "delete" } }
                if ( !isNullOrUndefined(fcmToken) ) { 
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, dataMsg, options);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return 0;
        })
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You're not returning anything in the final missing `else` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a code path that doesn't return a value.  Try filling in the space where my question is below:

```js
const dataMsg = { data: { type: "delete" } }
if ( !isNullOrUndefined(fcmToken) ) { 
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, dataMsg, options);
}
else {
    // what do you want to return here?
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! - Adding `return 0;` after the above if statement fixes the problem.